# How to use Javascript to pass a contenteditable to a form

Tags: javascript, php, html

First off, I saw the other posts regarding this topic and took them into account when creating my code, but it is not working meaning there are not errors with javascript or php, but the text is not being transferred or uploaded to the database.  Here is my code.  Thanks and as this is my first time using this forum please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                alert("Changes Saved");
            }
            function getContent()
            {
                document.getElementById("tdescription").value = document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("tcomments").value = document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("tannouncements").value = document.getElementById("announcements").innerHTML;
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php session_start(); ?>
        <?php include("pageview.php"); ?>
            <?php   
                if($edit == 1)
                {
                    echo "<div class='heading' style = 'width:70%;border-radius:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'><h3>Announcements</h3> <form name = 'form' action = 'edit_class.php' method = 'POST' onsubmit='return getContent()'><textarea style='display:none;' id = 'tannouncements' name = 'tannouncements'></textarea><p contenteditable = 'true' class = 'content' spellcheck = 'true' id = 'announcements'>";
                    echo $announcement;
                    echo " </p></div><div class='heading' style = 'width:70%;border-radius:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'><h3>Description</h3> <textarea style='display:none;' name = 'tdescription' name = 'tdescription'></textarea><p contenteditable = 'true' class = 'content' spellcheck = 'true' id = 'description'>";
                    echo $description;
                    echo "</p></div><div class='heading' style = 'width:70%;border-radius:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'><h3>Comments</h3><textarea style='display:none;' id = 'tcomments' name = 'tcomments'></textarea><p contenteditable = 'true' class = 'content' spellcheck = 'true' id = 'comments'>";
                    echo $comments;
                    echo "</p></div> <br> <input type = 'submit' value = 'Save Changes'> </form>";

                    echo "<br><h3>Upload Images</h3><form name = 'file_upload' action = 'upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method = 'POST'> Choose Image File: <input type = 'file' name = 'upload' style = 'font-size:14pt;'><br><br><input type = 'submit' name = 'upload_button' value = 'Upload Image'></form><br>";

                    $_SESSION['temp'] = $class;
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo "<div class='heading' style = 'width:70%;border-radius:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'> <h3>Announcements</h3> <p>";
                    echo $announcement;
                    echo "</p></div><div class='heading' style = 'width:70%;border-radius:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'> <h3>Description</h3> <p>";
                    echo $description;
                    echo "</p></div><div class='heading' style = 'width:70%;border-radius:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'><h3>Comments</h3><p>";
                    echo $comments;
                    echo "</p></div>";
                }
            ?>
       </body>
 </html>
```

PHP Database:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = new mysqli(x,x,x,x);



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $a = $_POST['tannouncements']; 
    $d = $_POST['tdescription'];
    $c = $_POST['tcomments'];
    $y = $_SESSION['temp'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE Class_data SET announcements = ?, description = ?, comments = ? WHERE class_year = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $a, $d, $c, $y);

    mysqli_error($con);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $header = "Location:classpage.php?class=" .$y. "";

    mysqli_close($con);
    header($header);
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry about the code's length...

Comment: There's nothing in this code that relates to database.

Comment: Oh sorry... let me edit that...

Comment: @OfirBaruch but I know that the PHP database interaction code is not the problem since when I used textareas it worked fine.

Comment: If that works fine, perhaps you could simplify the code to html/javascript and post a JSFiddle, so it's easier for people to try out why the submit doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is solely down to mistakenly setting the `name` property twice on `tdescription` instead of setting the `id` once as well.

`<textarea style='display:none;' name = 'tdescription' name = 'tdescription'>`

This causes referencing `document.getElementById('tdescription').value` to throw an error, which prevents the javascript from finishing.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N8CKa/ (I made the textareas visible, and onsubmit returns false so submit is not actually done)